# Strange BAD_ACCESS when printing NSInteger

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, memory-management

this is my first time asking something here, so don't be too harsh on me please :-). I have a strange "bad access" issue. In a class of mine I have a `NSInteger` along with a few other members. I override the `- (NSString *)description` method to print the values of everything like so (omitted the unrelevant part):

```
- (NSString *)description {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Duration:%d", duration];
}
```

and then I print that using `NSLog(@"%@", myObject)` which is giving me EXC_BAD_ACCESS without any log messages, regardless of the NSZombieEnabled.

- I have double checked the order of all formatting specifiers and
  parameters - it's correct.
- I tried changing the format specifier to `%i` and `%@` and didn't get any result
- When I init my object I don't initialize
  duration. Later, I assign it through a property `@property NSInteger
  duration`. So I tried initializing the duration to 0 in my `init`
  method but to no avail.
- If I box duration to a NSNumber prior to
  printing, it works.
- When I remove the duration and leave all the
  other ivars it works again.

I'm stumped, what am I doing wrong here?
   Can you help me?

Thanks a lot!

EDIT: To summarize, It seems this is caused by differences between 32 and 64 bit platforms, because it's fine when run on an iphone 4 and has issues only when run in the simulator. I tried 3 different approaches - using `%d` and `%i` with the NSInteger variable itself, using  `%qi` and using `%ld`/ `%lx` and I also tried to cast to `int` and `long` with the various format specifiers. Every time I can run on the device, but get EXC_BAD_ACCESS in the simulator.

Comment: Set a brakpoint in your method and read your "duration" value, I think it isn't set when you are there...

Comment: I did set a breakpoint at the NSLog - myObject is valid and it has a valid duration there... Thanks anyway Marco!

Comment: you don't have a macro called `duration` anywhere in your code do you?

Comment: No Nielsbot, I only have one called `kDurationTag`... Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only guess here: NSInteger could be 64 bit in your case and %i (as well as %d) expects 32-bit integer, you can try %qi or (what seems to be better) cast the value explicitly.

Comment: Hey Gobra, tried using `%qi` and `%qu` and also casting to `int` but nothing changes. I can go with the boxing option, but would like to know if I'm making a mistake somewhere... Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

When you run the app in the debugger, where **exactly** is the signal raised? Xcode will show you the precise line and stack of the problem.

When you are sure the crash happens in the `stringWithFormat:` method it's probably a matter of format specifiers. Apple's [String Programming Guide contains information](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004265-SW5) on how to handle `NSInteger` in a safe and platform independent way.

Comment: The signal comes from within the `stringWithFormat:` method. Thank you for the link Nikolai, I have referenced it a lot of times but have missed the bottom part about platform dependencies. However, when I use `%ld` or `%lx` and cast to (long) it only runs on the device (iphone 4), but in the simulator it still gives me a bad access. Same thing as when using `%d` or `%i` without a cast...

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you need to synthesyse your property?

Comment: I have already done that Padavan, I think that's not the problem. Thank you!